# Formal systems needed to formalize relative independence results

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, peano-arithmetic

We know that Con(ZF) implies Con(ZFC+GCH), Con(ZF+neg(AC)) and Con(ZFC+neg(CH)).  But what are some weak theories in which these relative independence results are provable? In particular, are they provable in PA and even in some interesting proper subtheories of PA?  Are there similar relative independence results whose proofs require more than PA or even ZFC?

Comment: I think that $\sf PRA$ should suffice for all this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Independence results such as the ones mentioned that can be proved using basic syntactic methods (relative interpretation, forcing) can be formalized in the theory $\mathit{PV}_1$ (also known as $T^0_2$, $\mathit{VP}$, and the $\forall\Sigma^b_1$-fragment of $S^1_2$): it has function symbols for all polynomial-time algorithms introduced by means of Cobham’s limited recursion on notation, and it can be axiomatized by definitional equations for the functions, a form of quantifier-free induction, and something to the effect of $0\ne1$ and $x\le1\to x=0\lor x=1$. This theory is as weak as it gets among usable fragments of arithmetic: it is interpretable in Robinson’s arithmetic $Q$ on a definable cut. It is included in $I\Delta_0+\Omega_1$, and a fortiori in stronger fragments of PA.

I should perhaps clarify how one deals with forcing, as it is conceptually a model-theoretic method. Let me take $\mathrm{Con}(\mathit{ZFC})\to\mathrm{Con}(\mathit{ZFC}+\neg\mathit{CH})$ for concreteness. In ZFC, you can define the relevant Cohen algebra $B$, and build the Boolean-valued universe $V^B$. In particular, for each formula $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, you can construct a definable function $\|\phi\|\colon(V^B)^n\to B$ that gives the truth value of $\phi$ in the Boolean universe. Then, in $\mathit{PV}_1$, you prove $\forall\phi\,(\mathit{ZFC}+\neg\mathit{CH}\vdash\phi\Rightarrow\mathit{ZFC}\vdash\|\phi\|=1)$ by induction on the structure of the proof.

There are some more demanding relative consistency results: in particular, the consistency of GB relative to ZF, or of $\mathit{ACA}_0$ relative to PA, rely on cut elimination; they are provable in $I\Delta_0+\mathit{SUPEXP}$, but not in $I\Delta_0+\mathit{EXP}$. This is still nowhere near as strong as PA or ZFC. I can’t recall any examples of the latter sort, and somewhat suspect that in most cases, if your relative consistency required such a strong theory, you could as well make it an *absolute* consistency result.

Comment: Actually, even a $\mathrm{TC}^0$ theory ($\mathit{VTC}^0$ or $\Delta^b_1\text-\mathit{CR}$) should be enough, but I have a feeling that introducing it here would be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you provide a reference for these theories?  I haven't heard of them before.  Also, are they also sufficient for proving relative independence results and relative consistency strengths of large cardinal axioms?

Comment: Standard references are J. Krajíček: Bounded arithmetic, propositional logic, and complexity theory, CUP, 1995; S. Cook, P. Nguyen: Logical foundations of proof complexity, CUP, 2010 (they work in a different setup; their two-sorted theories VP, VPV, and TV^0 are all equivalent to PV_1). And if you want a simple axiom system, the version of $T^0_2$ in http://math.cas.cz/~jerabek/papers/t02.pdf is also equivalent. I am not very familiar with large cardinals, so I’m not quite sure what kind of consistency results are out there. However, for constructions I am aware about: ...

Comment: ... First, a common case is that the existence of one cardinal outright implies the existence of another, or its consistency. Both immediately give a relative consistency result provable in PV_1, using just the Hilbert–Bernays–Löb derivability conditions. Other than that, inner models are just a special case of relative interpretation which I already mentioned in the answer (in principle, interpretations are not automatically verifiable in a weak theory as ZFC is not finitely axiomatized, but for inner models the replacement schema can be dealt with by a uniform proof), and the same goes ...

Comment: ... when it is combined with forcing. Is there anything else?

Comment: Oh, I forgot: arguments like “ZFC + A proves the consistency of ZFC + B, hence ZFC + B + ¬A is consistent relative to ZFC + B” are also fine: PV_1 proves Gödel’s theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I'm wondering about a related philosophical question, namely, can all of metamathematics be formalized in PA or weak subtheories of PA like $PV_1$?  In other words, are these theories sufficient for "reverse metamathematics"?  What's your opinion on this?  You may interpret the term "metamathematics" here as you see most fit.

Comment: I’m afraid this really depends too much on what you expect the metamathematics to do. In a narrow sense, you just need to get first-order logic going to support a formal theory such as ZFC (define formulas and proofs, prove little tidbits like unique readability). This can be certainly done in $\mathit{PV}_1$. On the other hand, in a broad sense, metamathematics includes pretty much all of logic, and you will need serious set theory to formalize e.g. model-theoretic arguments involving stuff like monster models. There is a broad range between these two extremes, and you need to judge for ...

Comment: ... yourself what is still essential to metamathematics, and what not. As I already mentioned, syntactic arguments involving all kinds of “translations” can be usually formalized in $\mathit{PV}_1$, however more sophisticated proof theoretic methods require more: basic cut-elimination works in $I\Delta_0+\mathit{SUPEXP}$, but arguments (e.g. in ordinal analysis) involving infinitary logic will probably need at least a decent fragment of second-order arithmetic. Basic model theory (e.g., the completeness theorem) will work in second-order arithmetic of strength below PA (e.g. $\mathit{WKL}_0$),

Comment: ... but more advanced tools will need more set theory. Gödel’s second incompleteness theorem is provable in $\mathit{PV}_1$, but Rosser-style witness comparison arguments and other applications of $\Sigma_1$-completeness of arithmetic for non-$\exists\Delta^b_0$ sentences need $I\Delta_0+\mathit{EXP}$. Semantics of typical decidable formal systems (propositional logic, various nonclassical logics, I guess also theories like Presburger arithmetic or RCF) can be usually handled in $I\Delta_0+\mathit{EXP}$. I’m not really sure what to make of all this.